# Get the first number in a string with multiple numbers?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a string (Oracle 11g) that could be something like this:

WORD1: 10.20 WORD2: 1112.30

Both numbers can vary in their size (can be dozens, hundreds or thousands) - although the words are fixed - and what I need is to extract the first number (including the decimal part). In the example above, it would be "10.20".

How can I achieve that? Basically what I need is to obtain the whole number between "WORD1" and "WORD2".

Comment: This is a sign for a bad database design. If you need numbers in a string, you should store them as numbers.  Maybe you have to add/change some tables for this.

Comment: Could it happen that you only have one WORD in the input string? That would need special handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the words are not varying, you need to get the substring from the 8th character, up to the first `'WORD2'` occurrence:

```
select substr( str, 8, instr(str, 'WORD2') -9)
from (
        select 'WORD1: 10.20 WORD2: 1112.30' str
        from dual
     )
```

Comment: ...with the distinct advantage of only using standard string functions (no regular expressions). At least in Oracle this will be a significant performance enhancement.